# Using shared classes for different views

Tags: ios, swift

I have an onboarding user flow:

```
Name -> Age -> Gender
```

Each of the screens shares the same structure:

```
Question (top)
Input (middle)
Continue (bottom)
```

I have a class OnboardingHelper.swift that creates a class to set the question box and continue button:

```
class UserOnboardingHelper{
   var text: String
   var questionbox: UIView
   var viewController: UIViewController
   var continueButton: UIButton

   init(text: String, questionbox: UIView, viewController: UIViewController, continueButton: UIButton){
      self.text = text
      self.questionbox = questionbox
      self.viewController = viewController
      self.continueButton = continueButton
   }
   func setQuestionBox(){
       //sets question box
   }
   func setContinueButton(){
       //sets continue button
       enableContinueButton()
       addContinueButtonPath()
   }
   func enableContinueButton(){
       //enables continue button
   }
   func disableContinueButton(){
       //disables continue button
   }
   func addContinueButtonPath(){
       //sets path of continue button based on which view
   }
}
```

In each of the onboarding ViewControllers I am setting the class in ViewDidLoad():

```
class NamePageViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelagate {
    @IBOutlet weak var questionbox: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var continueButton: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var inputLabel: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       let namePageSettings = UserOnboardingHelper(text: "What is your name", questionbox: questionbox, viewController: self, continueButton: continueButton)
       namePageSettings.setQuestionBox()
       namePageSettings.setContinueButton()
       inputLabel.delegate = self
       if nameIsFilled {
          namePageSettings.enableContinueButton()
       } else{
          namePageSettings.disableContinueButton()
       }
    }
}
```

The issue is that in the ViewController I textFieldDidEndEditing() function which needs to call the namePageSettings class from viewDidLoad()

```
    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField){
        if (textField.text?.empty)!{
            //I want to call disableContinueButton() from UserOnboardingHelper
        } else {
            //I want to enable enableContinueButton() from UserOnboardingHelper
        }
    }
```

Trying to understand if:

1. The overall approach is correct and if not, what's the best way
2. If the above approach is in the right direction, how should disableContinueButton() and enableContinueButton() be called?

Thanks in advance! Sorry if the approach is really dumb - I'm still trying to wrap my head around classes.

Comment: 1 UserOnboardingHelper must be shared between your controllers, i.e. you must not create new instance of Helper in each controller, but using global one,

Comment: @tereks - thank you for your response. Does this mean I should be using a singleton for UserOnboardingHelper?

Comment: Not at all, you can use helper that is owned by rootcontroller for example

Answer (score 0):

You can have the view controller have a weak reference to the onboarding helper, so you can still call helper methods without creating a retain cycle.

In `NamePageViewController`, add a property:

```
weak var userOnboardingHelper: UserOnboardingHelper?
```

Then, in `UserOnboardingHelper`'s initializer, add:

```
self.viewController.userOnboardingHelper = self
```

You can now call the onboarding helper's methods in the view controller:

```
userOnboardingHelper.disableContinueButton()
userOnboardingHelper.enableContinueButton()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - I am getting:

`Value of type 'UIViewController' has no member 'userOnboardingHelper`

When I add:
`self.viewController.userOnboardingHelper = self` 
in the initializer

Comment: @jackbauer The `viewController` property needs to be of type `NamePageViewController`. Consider a protocol if you need to have different view controller types for this property.